# How to read a CSS variable set in an @import'ed stylesheet in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-variables, css-import

Given the following file structure

*app.css*

```
@import https://foo.css

html {
  --green: #ff0;
}
```

*https://foo.css/*

```
html {
  --red: #f00;
}
```

How do I read `--red`?

### Already tried

*app.tsx*

```
...
useLayoutEffect(() => {

  // works
  const green = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--green');

  // doesn't work
  const red = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--red');
})
```

I've already tried waiting for frames with `setTimeout` and `requestAnimationFrame` to no avail.
If I `setTimeout(() => {...}, 10000)` the variable is there so I know it's only a synchronisation issue, but I have no idea on how to get the update.

Comment: You've written `getComputeStyle` for the second one. Are you sure its not a typo?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote code by hand here but it's ok in the project, let me fix the typo

Comment: Not entirely sure if that is the problem, but I think your `foo.css` might be loaded as `text/html` instead of `text/css`, hence browser doesn't treat it as css file. Check Network tab under developer tools to see if that is the case.

Comment: @Morpheus it's loaded as CSS